# Using substr_count within a nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to pull out certain groups of keywords from a block of text using substr_count and have it count how many times the words in each group appears.

I've created an array called $keywords, within it is another set of arrays which contain the actual keywords I am looking for.

This is my current code:

```
$textDump = "random bunch of text";

$keyWordsSports = array("nba", "raptor", "ufc", "basektball", "gym", "mma", "realgm", "running");
$keyWordsTech = array("apple", "rim", "blackberry", "facebook", "twitter", "google" );
$keywords = array($keyWordsSports, $keyWordsTech);
foreach ($keywords as $item){
    foreach ($item as $newItem){
        $number += substr_count(strtolower($textDump), strtolower($newItem));
        echo $number;
    };
};
```

My problem is that it counts all the keywords within all the arrays and adds everything together, what I want is just the total for each group of keywords. Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$keywords = array("sports"=>$keyWordsSports, "tech"=>$keyWordsTech);
$count=array("sports"=>0,"tech"=>0);
foreach ($keywords as $key=>$item){
    foreach ($item as $newItem){
        $count[$key] += substr_count(strtolower($textDump), strtolower($newItem));
    }
}
print_r($count);
```

**Edit**: [Live example](http://3v4l.org/3UNXA)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$textDump = "raptor bunch raptor basektball";

$keyWordsSports = array("nba", "raptor", "ufc", "basektball", "gym", "mma", "realgm", "running");
$keyWordsTech = array("apple", "rim", "blackberry", "facebook", "twitter", "google" );
$keywords = array($keyWordsSports, $keyWordsTech);
$matches=array();
foreach ($keywords as $item){
    foreach ($item as $newItem){
        $number = substr_count(strtolower($textDump), strtolower($newItem));
        if($number>0)
        {
        $matches[strtolower($newItem)]=$number;
        }
    };
};
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to `echo` the `$number` outside the inner `foreach`
like this,

```
$textDump = "random bunch of text";
$keyWordsSports = array("nba", "raptor", "ufc", "basektball", "gym", "mma", "realgm", "running");
$keyWordsTech = array("apple", "rim", "blackberry", "facebook", "twitter", "google" );
$keywords = array($keyWordsSports, $keyWordsTech);
foreach ($keywords as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $newItem) {
        $number += substr_count(strtolower($textDump), strtolower($newItem));
    }
    echo $number;
}
```